# Set the Location where Update-Help Installs Help Files in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-7

I just installed PowerShell 7 and ran `Update-Help -Force -UICulture en-us` to install all the help files. This all works well enough, only I then noticed that it installed them in `C:/Users/<me>/OneDrive/Documents/PowerShell/Help`. I do not want the files in OneDrive, I want them in the pwsh installation folder.

First, I figured that changing `PSModulePath` would probably also affect where help files are stored. I checked `$env:PSModulePath` (in the pwsh window) and found that, indeed, the first entry is `C:/Users/<me>/OneDrive/Documents/PowerShell/Modules`.
The system value for `PSModulePath` is `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;`. I tried changing the it and I tried editing `powershell.config.json`, but [neither will change anything about the fact that "PS7 User, System, and $PSHOME paths" are prepended to the variable when pwsh starts up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath?view=powershell-7.3#powershell-psmodulepath-construction).

I tried just manually setting `PSModulePath` and then running `Update-Help` from within pwsh, but that doesn't work either. After this, I ran `gci $env` in that same pwsh windows and the only places where `C:/Users/<me>/OneDrive/Documents` shows up at all are the `OneDrive` and `OneDriveCommercial` variables. These are also the only system environment variables that reference `C:/Users/<me>/OneDrive/Documents`. So apparently, PowerShell is explicitly configured to use OneDrive as the first location for installing modules? How else could this come about? the `pwsh` start program is an executable, so I can't really look inside it either.

I've also tried letting it install the help files in my OneDrive folder, then copying them to various locations and `<entry>/Modules`, `<entry>/en-US` locations on the `PSModulePath`. But wherever I put them, once they are gone from the OneDrive folder, `get-help get-help` says the usual "`Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.`" message.

I'm starting to think that there is actually no relation at all between the `PSModulePath` and where the help files are stored and searched for.

There seem to be [various options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help?view=powershell-7.3) for determining where `Update-Help` gets the help files, but none for deciding where to save them.

So yeah: how do I decide where help files are installed, if changing `PSModulePath` is not it? I'll settle for some workaround for now, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want them in the pwsh installation folder.

Pass **`-Scope AllUsers`** to [`Update-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help) (which works in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *only*) to avoid targeting *user-specific locations*.

Note that this option **typically<sup>[1]</sup> requires *elevation*** (running with admin privileges).

---

Note:

- **`-Scope CurrentUser` vs. `-Scope AllUsers`** (which is the *invariably implied* default in *Windows PowerShell*) in PowerShell 7+ allows you an ***abstract* choice between user-level and all-users locations, but you do *not* get to control what *specific directories* are targeted** as a result.

  - Indeed, it appears that you can *not* control the target directories via [`$env:PSModulePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSModulePath).
- Specifically:

  - With **`-Scope CurrentUser`** (the *default* in v7+):

    - Updates to any modules - whether third-party or not - are stored in the following user-level locations, in folders that *parallel* the actual module folders:

      - **Windows**: `"$(Split-Path $PROFILE)\Help"`
      - **Unix**-like platforms: `"$HOME/.local/share/powershell/Help"`
  - With **`-Scope AllUsers`** (which typically requires _elevation):

    - Updates to the help content of modules that are either *built into* or *ship with* PowerShell are made to subfolders of `$PSHOME`, PowerShell's installation folder.
    - *Third-party* modules that support [updatable help content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/supporting-updatable-help) are updated *in-place*, irrespective of where they're installed, assuming they're discoverable via [`$env:PSModulePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSModulePath).

---

<sup>[1] Given that it's possible to install PowerShell (Core) in a *user-specific location*, elevation isn't necessary in that case.</sup>